# Java Multiplication table GUI, please help me move forward

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

First time user here, so please bear with me...I want to create a code that asks the user for the number of rows and columns they want to create multiplication table, but I honestly don't know where to go from here...Can someone help? I'd like for some specifics...such as...create a for loop here for this purpose...

sorry if my code is not formatted correctly...this is what i have so far..it correctly asks the user for a number of rows and columns and displays those rows and columns..I want to make it so once the user clicks a button at a certain intersection, the answer will be displayed.

For example: the first button when clicked will display "1*1=1"

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SquareGrid {

    private int rowCount;
    private int colCount;

    public SquareGrid(int rowCount, int colCount){
        this.rowCount=rowCount;
        this.colCount= colCount;            
    }

    JFrame theFrame;
    JButton[][] buttons;
    JPanel panel;

    private void createAndShowGui(){
        theFrame = new JFrame ("grid");
        buttons = new JButton[rowCount][colCount];
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowCount, colCount));            
        for(int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rowCount; rowCounter++)
            for(int colCounter = 0; colCounter < colCount; colCounter++){
                final JButton j = new JButton("not clicked");
                j.setActionCommand((rowCount + 1) * (colCount + 1)  + "");
                j.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    boolean clicked = false;
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        if(clicked == false) clicked = true;
                        else clicked = false;
                        if (clicked) {
                            j.setText(j.getActionCommand());                            
                        }   
                    }
                    });
                String event;
                buttons[rowCounter][colCounter] = j;            
                panel.add(j);
            }
        theFrame.add(panel);
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theFrame.pack();
        theFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
        int rowCount=input.nextInt();           
        Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
        int colCount=input1.nextInt();
        SquareGrid h = new SquareGrid(colCount,rowCount);
        h.createAndShowGui();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make it so once the user clicks a button at a certain intersection, the answer will be displayed.
>
> For example: the first button when clicked will display "1*1=1"

You can set the `actionCommand` in your loop, with the multiplication already done from your loop count.

```
final JButton j = new JButton("not clicked");
j.setActionCommand((rowCounter + 1) * (colCounter + 1)  + "");
```

Then just use that `actionCommand`

```
if (clicked) {
    j.setText(j.getActionCommand());
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Not sure what you changed, but try this

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SquareGrid {

    private int rowCount;
    private int colCount;

    public SquareGrid(int rowCount, int colCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.colCount = colCount;

    }
    JFrame theFrame;
    JButton[][] buttons;

    JPanel panel;

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        theFrame = new JFrame("grid");
        buttons = new JButton[rowCount][colCount];
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowCount, colCount));

        for (int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rowCount; rowCounter++) {
            for (int colCounter = 0; colCounter < colCount; colCounter++) {
                final JButton j = new JButton("not clicked");
                j.setActionCommand((rowCounter + 1) * (colCounter + 1) + "");
                j.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    boolean clicked = false;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        if(clicked == false) clicked = true;
                        else clicked = false;

                        if (clicked) {
                            j.setText(j.getActionCommand());

                        } else {
                            j.setText("not clicked");
                        }

                    }
                });
                buttons[rowCounter][colCounter] = j;
                panel.add(j);
                JButton buttonClicked = (j);  //THIS WAS ADDED

            }
        }
        theFrame.add(panel);
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theFrame.pack();
        theFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
        int rowCount = input.nextInt();

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
        int colCount = input1.nextInt();

        SquareGrid h = new SquareGrid(colCount, rowCount);
        h.createAndShowGui();
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT! I'm getting close...so when i click a button now, i simply get the math that is done by the "j.setActionCommand((rowCount + 1) * (colCount + 1)  + "");"

Comment: Which will always be 36 if the user enters 5 rows and 5 columns..how can i make it so it creates a condition and does the math differently? how do i structure the loop?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? What do you mean _" creates a condition and does the math differently?"_

Comment: if you can run my code, and enter 5 for both prompts..when you click a button after entering those prompts, you will get 36 for them all...am i supposed to create another nested for loop to fix this?

Comment: What i meant by creates a condition, is, everytime the user enters a different number for row or column, it stores that information and creates the table differently

Comment: Yeah, i fixed it. Thanks for the help :). I also want to create like numbers on the left and top of the buttons, like in a multiplication table...see pic: "http://www.ttinet.com/doc/sp4gl/images/matrix_display.jpg"...basically i just want like numbers that are not buttons (just written) on the left and top...any hints on that?

Answer (score 2):

When a button is clicked, you can tell which button has been clicked by getting it from the event:

```
JButton buttonClicked = (JButton) event.getSource();
```

All you need to do now is to find the row and the column of this button inside your 2D array of buttons, and to compute the multiplication.

PS: you don't even have to use `event.getSource()` to get the button, since you already have the `j` variable referencing this button.

EDIT:the row and columns are available from the outside variables, which simply need to be made final:

```
for(int rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < rowCount; rowCounter++)
    for(int colCounter = 0; colCounter < colCount; colCounter++){
        final JButton j = new JButton("not clicked");
        final int row = rowCounter;
        final int col = colCounter;

        // now you can use row and col inside your listener.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried to find the row and column from my 2D array but nothing happens...I tried this "JButton buttonClicked = (j);"..would that be correct? I want to store the reference to the row and column from the array then do the computation on that...sorry for these dumb questions, but i have only been programming for 3 weeks...

Comment: Then I really advise you to stop using Swing, which is quite complex, and practice with simple exercices using arrays and loops.

Answer (score 0):

John Hurley's CS202 class ROFL -John Hurley's CS202 class ROFL

Comment: Correct- you are very observant.

Comment: I guess I should put in that its been revised from the lecture notes, so credit is given where credit is due.